# Panel BBar buttons being cut off

Tags: layout, extjs

I have a display problem with my extjs app that I need advice on how to resolve.  I have a seemingly innocent Panels with buttons in the bottom toolbar dispersed on the different views of my app.  The problem is that the buttons are not being fully displayed.

Here's the way they should look:
[image]

And here's what is happening:
[image]

I've played around a little with doLayout(), but it still cuts the buttons off.  Here's a good clue:  resizing the browser window makes the page resize and the buttons display as they're supposed to.  Subsequent visits to that page are fine.

Any ideas?

Here's (roughly) my panel nesting:

```
ViewPort
--Card Panel (center)
----Card Panel
------Form Panel <-- mis-rendered bbar is here.
```

Thanks for any help on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't a layout issue.  The problem was that the panel with the bbars was having its title dynamically set, `panel.setTitle()`.  We had put a place holder in there: `title: ''`,which allowed the title to be set later on during code execution (otherwise setting the title would do nothing), but then this problem showed up.  The fix was to set something in the title that had characters in it:  `title:'UNINITIALIZED TITLE'`.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Without code there's no way to tell.  However I'd guess that you're missing a `layout` config at some level in your hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll check it out and post my results.